# Can I use Autolayout to dynamically resize a UITableViewCell into zero-height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've created a fairly simple tableview cell xib that is dequeued into my table and configured with a button, label, and UIActivityIndicatorView. In an attempt to achieve zero height for this cell, I added a method for the cell's class that activates an NSLayoutConstraint for making the button's height anchor zero.
[image]

For some reason the cell gets this "45". Disabling translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints seems non-standard.

Important Edit:

The exact same code that results in this arbitrary 45 points of height **works as expected if I give my "zero-height" constraint a value of 0.5**, instead resulting in a very short table cell!

This tells me that there is a special exception in the internal calculation when the content has zero points in size.

I'm still looking for a solution to overcome this erroneous result.

Comment: use the tableview's `heightForRow` delegate method to set the height to 0, otherwise it will use the `rowHeight` property of the tableView as the default.

Comment: @Rog That's actually the way I achieved this originally. However I'm looking for a solution that works through cell configuration. That will allow me a general solution that doesn't require ad-hoc code in each of my tables.

Comment: Yeah I don't think you will be able to do that unfortunately. I think the crux of it is that it's the tableview's job to work out the size of each cell, not the cell itself.

Comment: @Rog. Not so. See this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: Yeah I understand cells can do dynamic resizing. Have you tried setting the tableView's `estimatedRowHeight` to 0 and letting the cell dynamically resize?

Comment: Unfortunately that change breaks the autolayout somehow. The dynamic sizing does work for most cases, however when the cell content dictates zero-height, it freaks out and gives me 45 points.